# What is log level in RASA? What is its purpose?

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu

[image: 1]

I am  new to this environment. help me find out what this is for

some commands are also given.

```
LOG_LEVEL_LIBRARIES=ERROR LOG_LEVEL_MATPLOTLIB=WARNING LOG_LEVEL_KAFKA=DEBUG rasa shell --debug

LOG_LEVEL_LIBRARIES=DEBUG LOG_LEVEL_MATPLOTLIB=DEBUG rasa shell --verbose
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about the messages you could probably see when you run or train your rasa. Rasa offers you the option to activate/desactivate logs for external libraries. You can do so by setting these environment variable.
For example for MacOS you can do so by typing in your CLI: `export VARIABLE_NAME=VARIABLE_VALUE`
You can read more about this here:

- [For macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x)
- [For windows](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/)